# Как правильно заготовить массив картинок для рисования?

Tags: java, android

Задача: заготовить (нарисовать в памяти) массив картинок ("символы своего шрифта"), чтобы потом их выводить на Canvas в разных местах, накладывая на фон (который тоже меняется динамически). 
Как их нарисовать в памяти? Как их потом разместить на Canvas? 
В виде примера.

Comment: Вы не понимаете как обращаться с массивами обьектов?

Comment: C простыми массивами сложностей нет, а когда столкнулся с массивами элементов типа Point, возникли сложности. Ну и хотелось бы услышать соображения по поводу рисования. Правильный ли подход или надо как-то по другому эту задачу решать.

Comment: `Paint` - это не картинка.

Comment: Да, я уже понял что написал бред. Paint это один из их
параметров для рисования. В нем задаются графические характеристики рисования. Можно считать, что это кисть, которой будут рисоваться фигуры.

Comment: metalargus, у меня к вам есть деловое предложение. Как с вами можно связаться? моя почта intent2joy@mail.ru

Answer (score 1):

Почитай про ArrayList
https://habrahabr.ru/post/128269/

HashMap
https://habrahabr.ru/post/128017/

По сути, задача имеет несколько способов решения. Можно хранить как сами рисунки, тогда будем плясать от строки вроде этой:

```
ArrayList<PaintObject> list = new ArrayList<PaintObject>();
```

Или этой, если рисунки будут вставляться по определенным правилам:

```
Map<Key,PaintObject> list = new Map<>(Key,PaintObjec);
```

Так и ссылки на рисунки, которые просто хранятся в виде отдельных файлов, тогда это будет массив строк или обьектов на основе своего класса, где будет храниться строка и ключ.
В любом случае - по организации массива полно информации, тебе лишь надо выбрать, будет ли это HashMap, Map, ArrayList или что-то иное.
Важно ведь не только хранение - важно еще, какие методы обработки этого массива будут. Нужен ли поиск? Случайная вставка или по каким-то правилам? Добавление новых элементов в массив?
Вопрос расплывчат немного, правильная организация в одном случае, будет неверной в другом. Но насколько я понял - вполне подойдет Map.

З.Ы. Игра Балда что-ли?))))

Comment: Если массив состоит из уникальных картинок - можно еще Set использовать.

Comment: Рисунки ("символы", "новый шрифт") создаются в памяти, а не грузятся в виде файлов. Создаются в начале работы (в памяти в виде массива картинок) и дальше просто используются как "новые шрифты".

Comment: TreeMap я думаю будет самое то. В любом случае будет пара ключ_буква-объект_рисунок. Почитать, как организовать можно тут.http://www.quizful.net/post/Java-TreeMap